# Unable to get two fields in mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have four fields in my `route` table

`busid, routid, position and distance`

I want to show `busid and distance from a select query`. My select query is as follow :

```
$endb = mysql_query("select case when a.position < b.position then a.busid when a.position > b.position then a.busid else null end as busid, a.distance as distance from (select busid,position from route where routid=$result2) a join (select busid,position from route where routid=$end) b on a.busid = b.busid") or die(mysql_error());
```

but when I use this query then it gives error :  `unknown field distance in field list`. Plese help what I am missing

Comment: I have distance in field list

Comment: oh, ok. (I didn't downvoted BTW)

Comment: your subquery for < a > doesn't have < distance > field, add that field  in subquery for alias < a > and for < b > and try !

Comment: how can I define this pleea help me

Comment: you need to select distance also in your subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing distance in sub-query a

```
select 
    case 
        when a.position < b.position then a.busid 
        when a.position > b.position then a.busid 
        else null 
    end as busid, 
    a.distance as distance 
from (
    select busid, position, distance
    from route 
    where routid=$result2
) as a join (
    select busid, position 
    from route 
    where routid=$end
) as b 
on a.busid = b.busid
```

Even a better version:

```
SELECT if (a.position <> b.position, a.busid, null) busid, a.distance
FROM  route a, route b
WHERE a.busid = b.busid
AND   a.routid= $result2
AND   b.routid= $end
```

Comment: The keyword AS is optional and not needed. probably typo as noted above.

Comment: Yes keyword AS is optional

Comment: For anyone reading this:  although the solution is technically correct, it is not the best way to write the query.  MySQL materializes subqueries, which incurs overhead and prevents the use of indexes for further processing.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use subqueries in the `from` clause, unless necessary in MySQL.  They prevent the optimizer from generating the best query plan.

A better way to write the query:

```
select (case when a.position < b.position then a.busid
             when a.position > b.position then a.busid 
        end) as busid,
       a.distance
from route a join
     route b
     on a.busid = b.busid and
        a.routid = $result2 and b.routid = $end;
```

Your specific problem, of course, is that `a.distance` is not defined because it was not defined in the subquery.

Comment: Yes this answer is better

Comment: +1. The CASE expression could be further simplified with a single inequality comparison `WHEN a.position <> b.position`.